# How to have a type that depends of another type c++

Tags: c++, class, templates, types

I want to implement `std::iterator_traits` to better understand `concepts`, `requires`. In `cppreference`, they say `If Iter does not have pointer, but has all four remaining member types, then the member types are declared as follows` `[...]` `Otherwise, if Iter satisfies the exposition-only concept __LegacyInputIterator, the member types are declared as follows` `[...]` `Otherwise, if Iter satisfies the exposition-only concept __LegacyIterator, the member types are declared as follows` `[...]`, But I don't figure out how to check if `Iter` types exist without throwing an error at compilation and didn't find much documentation about that on internet.
What could be the standard `C++20`'ish way to do that ?

Comment: If you don't want to deal with compilation errors, you can use `std::conditional` to switch between the existing iterator and the your own stub.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question `Iter` is a template parameter of `std::iterator_traits` class template, it always "exists"? Can you perhaps make a code example to illustrate the problem?

Comment: @ShamilMukhetdinov Yeah I know about `std::conditionnal`, but it needs a first `bool` argument to choose between two types, but how could I optain a `false` if the type doesn't exist and a `true` if the type exists ?

Comment: @Quimby I know that `Iter` exists, I want to be able to check if the types inside `Iter` exist (for example `Iter::pointer`)

Comment: *" I want to be able to check for example if Iter::pointer exists"* That's where concepts come in. To test for a pointer member, you can use `requires { typename Iter::pointer; }` , and that returns true or false.

Comment: @BoP Where do I need to put the `requires` clause ? When I put it under the template of my `iterator_traits` class, it says `requires does not name a type` at compil

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I just had to pass a concept as boolean through template like this:
(Example for pointer type)

```cpp
template < class T >
concept HasPointerType = requires { typename T::pointer; };

template < class T, bool >
struct _iterator_traits { };

template < class T >
struct _iterator_traits< T, false > {
    typedef void pointer;
};

template < class T >
struct _iterator_traits< T, true > {
    typedef typename T::pointer pointer;
};

template < class T >
struct iterator_traits : public _iterator_traits< T, HasPointerType< T > > { };
```

and now if I do for example:

```cpp
cout << typeid(::iterator_traits<int>::pointer).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(::iterator_traits<vector<int>::iterator>::pointer).name() << endl;
```

it successfully displays

```
v
Pi
```

because the types are respectively `void` and `int*`